# Access db from a separate file flask SQLAlchemy python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a flask application. I have two files. main.py and databases.py. I want to create a database from the database.py file. The main.py should access the databases.py file and create the database and table named "Users". But it shows import error. Help me with this issue

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from databases import User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/data_log.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

databases.py

```
from main import db
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context

class User(db.Model) :
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id     =   db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username    =   db.Column(db.String(32), index = True)
    password    =   db.Column(db.String(128))
    def hash_password(self, password) :
        self.password =pwd_context.hash(password)
    def verify_password(self, password) :
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from databases import User
  File "/home/paulsteven/stack/databases.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import db
  File "/home/paulsteven/stack/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from databases import User
ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a regular case of *cyclic imports* conflict.
The traceback gives you a clear steps:

How it  goes in steps:

- you run `main.py`
- the control flow starts importing features/libraries till it gets the 3rd line
  `from databases import User`.
- it goes to the `databases` module to find the needed `User` class. But ... the `User` may use the outer scope features (and it does require `db.Model`), so the control flow needs to scan `databases` module from the start. This reflects the 2nd step from traceback (`"/home/paulsteven/stack/databases.py", line 1`)
- from the position of previous step being at `database.py` the control flow encounters `from main import db` - ***that means it should turn back to the `main`(`main.py`) module!***
- control flow returned to the `main` module start scanning again from the 1st line - till it finds `from databases import User` **again**. This reflects the traceback's 3rd step (`File "/home/paulsteven/stack/main.py", line 3`)

  - and you run into cycle ...

---

What is right way to solve the issue?
Keep all DB context/DB models in separate module(s).
Follow the sequence of objects relations and how they depend on each other:

---> Application instantiated first (`app`)

- ---> then DB framework instance is created `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` depending on `app`

  - ---> then custom DB models created (like `User(db.Model)`) depending on `db` instance

---

***main.py***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# from databases import User  <--- shouldn't be here

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/data_log.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from databases import User  #  after instantiating `db` import model(s) 
    db.create_all()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

---

Comment: How to make it create a table in the db by using the User class in the databases.py file??

Comment: @PaulSteven, see the update. Use models after instantiating `db`

Comment: Now the class was imported successfuly. Eventhough the table was not created yet.

Comment: @PaulSteven, add `db.session.commit()` after `db.create_all()`

Comment: no table created even after adding `db.session.commit()` after `db.create_all()`. It creates a file only.

Comment: @PaulSteven, that starts annoying me! Do check your sqlalchemy version, then try to use `create_engine` instead of your current config. Optionally, you may try to create `Base = declarative_base()`. Do check all that!

Comment: ok... thanks for the response. i used your way of create_engine and declarative_base and it was solved.....thanks for the idea...

Comment: @PaulSteven, sorry for emotions